# Why does future.types.newstr.newstr.str.__mod__ return Unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2to3

I'm working on the support of Python 2 and 3 at the same time and I have some weird things that I wasn't able to understand so far.

I'm using the [python-future](https://python-future.org/) module in order to achieve this transition. When I use the `__mod__` function on an `newstr` object, my output is an `unicode` while I would expect it to be `newstr`. Am I missing something?

```py
>>> from builtins import str # provided by the future module to allow smooth transition from Py2 to Py3
>>> str('%s %s') % (u'Hello', u'World')
u'Hello World'
>>> type(str('%s %s') % (u'Hello', u'World'))
<type 'unicode'>
```

Answer (score 1):

`%` is a Python 2 built-in operator, which, unless overloaded, has no knowledge about *python-future* module.

The documentation says:

> If the object or format provided is a unicode string, the resulting string will also be unicode.

That explains the result you get.

More information:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: The first sentence *may* be incorrect/irrelevant. +1 for the rest.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the sentence to make it more relevant/accurate